# Registry key for Flash in Microsoft Edge

Tags: c#, flash, microsoft-edge

I need to Enable/Disable Flash for Edge pragmatically in C#. I googled the registry key which are below, but none of them works to enable Flash on Edge. Can someone tell me that what registry key is get used to to enable Flash on Edge on Windows 2016.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER \ SOFTWARE \ Classes \ Local Settings \ Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppContainer \ Storage \ microsoft.microsoftedge_8wekyb3d8bbwe \ MicrosoftEdge \ Addons\
```

and set the FlashPlayerEnabled = 1.

another one is:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\MicrosoftEdge\Addons
```

and set the FlashPlayerEnabled = 1.

Comment: If you're just asking for where the registry settings are, this should be asked on https://superuser.com instead.

Comment: Thanks Tyler. I will post the same on superuser.com as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the second approach in your question is right. I've tested it on Microsoft Edge 44.18362.1.0 on Windows 10 and it works. The approach is also listed in [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/deploy/group-policies/adobe-settings-gp#allow-adobe-flash). But we also need to notice that the supported versions is **Microsoft Edge on Windows 10**.

Second, Microsoft Edge is not supported on Windows Server 2016. It might be many features not supported even though you have successfully installed Microsoft Edge on Windows Server 2016. This might be the reason why the registry not working on Windows 2016 and I don't see there's a solution for this. From [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/deploy/about-microsoft-edge), we can see:

> The Long-Term Servicing Branch (LTSB) versions of Windows, **including Windows Server 2016, don’t include Microsoft Edge** or many other Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps. Systems running the LTSB operating systems do not support these apps because their services get frequently updated with new functionality. For customers who require the LTSB for specialized devices, we recommend using Internet Explorer 11.

So I think the best solution is trying to use IE 11 on Windows Server 2016.

-------------------------------------------------------------Edit-------------------------------------------------------------

For Microsoft Edge Chromium, you could refer to the registry key [DefaultPluginsSetting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployEdge/microsoft-edge-policies#defaultpluginssetting) and [PluginsAllowedForUrls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployEdge/microsoft-edge-policies#pluginsallowedforurls). From the explanation in DefaultPluginsSetting:

> The **PluginsAllowedForUrls** policies take precedence over DefaultPluginsSetting. If you want to enable automatic playback for all sites, consider adding `http://*` and `https://*` to this list.

So we only need to add values in registry under path:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\PluginsAllowedForUrls
```

The values are like below:

[image]

And the result is [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWNZF.png) in Microsoft Edge Chromium. From the docs, the supported versions are Microsoft Edge on Windows and Mac since version 77 or later. You could have a try in Windows Server 2016.

Comment: Thank you do much for the information Yu. it helped me to know why those keys were not working for me on window serve 2016.

Comment: have one question as you have tested the Edge on w10. I don't think that is chromium version of edge yet as it is being released on January 15 2020. i have beta version of Edge chromium on window server 2016 but both the above keys does not work for flash on window 2016 with edge chromium version. Not sure if those key will work on w10 with  Edge chromium version. And Microsoft it self mention that Edge chromium version is compatible with W8, W10, W7 and MacOS.

Comment: @User1 I've updated my answer, you could check it. I test on Microsoft Edge Chromium on Windows 10 and it works.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer Yu Zhou. I added both the above key (DefaultPluginsSettings and PluginsAllowedForUrls)in window server 2016 at the location HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\MicrosoftEdge  but unfortunately it did't not work on Window server 2016..:(. I have Microsoft Edge beta version because official version is releasing on 15 January 2020. I have Microsoft Edge Beta Chromium version 79.

Comment: i was expecting the key that you have mentioned will work as the same keys works for the google chrome i had worked with the same key for chrome and  Edge chromium and google chrome both have the same engine(chromium) but it didn't work or i guess i have to wait till official version will get released and try the same keys again.

Comment: I also test with Microsoft Edge Beta 79. Please pay attention, the last part of the location is **Microsoft\Edge**, not **MicrosoftEdge**.

Comment: I set up a VM with Windows Server 2016 and just finish the test on it. The registry key can work. You could check my [test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7SFY.png). Please check again if you have set the right path and reboot the browser after editing the registry.

Comment: ok....so i have created the whole path manually. I created the Edge folder under Microsoft and then added the rest of the keys under it and it did work. Thanks a ton for the help Yu. You are awesome.

Comment: Thanks...Thanks..Thanks a ton Yu for providing me the answer.